# Finding out input devices connected to the system through an ASP.NET webpage

Tags: asp.net, input-devices

I am using ASP.NET and C# in my project.

I have a requirement where I need to find out list of input devices that are connected to the user's computer. For instance, if he has a scanner and a webcam connected then I need to populate scanner and webcam in my dropdown and when the user selects any one of them I need to run the webcam or scanner. I know this is not possible with ASP.NET due to security reasons.

Just wanted to know if it is possible at all. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Wow, was your caps lock key stuck on when you typed that question title? Please put a little more effort in next time.

Comment: @slugster , thanks there are many ways to let a newbie know about some mistake , that was your style i guess , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar problem and we solve it using xbap (full security) embedded in the IFrame of the asp.net web page. But our project was only supported in IE, that could be problem, other wise activex or something.

If you want to use xbap then let me know. I will be happy to assist you for any help required.

Edit --- -----
Our requirements were opening third party exe files (say abcd.exe) from user computer, run them. Then user do 
tests with their third party device (abcd.exe), close the device. Third party put the results of test in location of file system on user machine. Then we read those files from user machine.

Xbap (with full security) has all the permissions a desktop windows application will have, search google for xbap get a idea and any help required just ask.

Edit -
For support of other browsers, following is the link -
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/538fb77a-193c-4e1f-bccd-30395ab4f30c

Few points about the XBap -
1. I think it will work only for windows OS.
2. User need to install .net 4.0 framework (client version will do).
3. User need to give permission before start for the first time on xbap for full security.

Thanks,
Daljit

Comment: thanks not a bad idea to start atleast , could you explain me what your requirement was , and then may be guide me as well.Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot , will search for Xbap , but as you said it was working only with IE right?Any workaround for other browsers.